# Migration problem in .NET 8 and EF Core 8 preview version (unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I am facing problems while I am trying to database migration in .NET 8 and EF Core 8. I get this error:

```
PM> add-migration initial
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.Clone(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingInfo ByRef)'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

My `.csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0-preview.1.23111.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0-preview.1.23111.4">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Core.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My `DbContext` class is:

```
namespace SQLServer.Db;

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In this case: how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you want a type here: DbContextOptions options  Maybe use: DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options

Comment: I tried this. still it is not working.

Comment: first line there is a little odd, too... shouldn't that be "namespace SQLServer.Db { ...the class code... }"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce your problem and solve it, you can refer to the below steps, hope it can help you.

To keep packages the same version Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1"  not preview  Version="8.0.0-preview.1.23111.4", and add package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

Try to modify .csproj `<ItemGroup>` like the below code
:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0-rc.2.23509.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Besides,  add the DbContext like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**Note** to rebuild your project.

result:

[image]

Comment: to clarify: the solution here was to check the EF dependet packages to be on the same release level as EF Core (for OP it was `SqlServer` `-preview` vs `-rc2`, for me it was `Npgsql` `-rc1` vs `-rc2`).