# EF Core 8 Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0, ef-core-8.0

I am facing problems while I am trying to database migration in .NET 8 and EF Core 8. I get this error:

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.Clone(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingInfo ByRef)
```

detail:

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.Clone(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingInfo ByRef)'.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.Clone(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingInfo ByRef)'.
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlTypeMappingSource.FindMapping(RelationalTypeMappingInfo& mappingInfo)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.<>c.<FindMappingWithConversion>b__8_0(ValueTuple`4 k, RelationalTypeMappingSource self)
         at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, Type providerClrType, ValueConverter customConverter)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, IReadOnlyList`1 principals)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMapping(MemberInfo member)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.MemberClassifier.IsCandidatePrimitiveProperty(MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionModel model, CoreTypeMapping& typeMapping)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.Process(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelConfigurationBuilder.CreateModelBuilder(ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
```

my project：

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.0-beta.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

`AppContext` .

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Xxxx.DataAccess;

public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     xxx
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Book> Book{ get; set; }
}
```

`BaseModel` .

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace xxx;

/// <summary>
///     base
/// </summary>
[Index(nameof(Id), IsUnique = true)]
public class BaseModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     pk
    /// </summary>
    [Comment("pk")]
    [Key]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
}
```

`Book` class.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace xxx;

[Table("xxx")]
[Comment("xxx")]
[Index(nameof(Id))]
public class Book: BaseModel
{
    

/// <summary>
///     Name
/// </summary>
[MaxLength(40)]
[StringLength(40)]
[Comment("Name")]
public string? Name{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     PRICE
    /// </summary>
    [Comment("Price")]
    [Column("Price", TypeName = "decimal(11,2)")]
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
}
```

`IBaseRepository` interface.

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace xxx;

public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
 Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, bool isIncludeDelete = false);
}
```

My `BaseRepository` class.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace xxx.Repository;

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    protected IDbContextFactory<AppContext> _dbContextFactory;
   

    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<AppContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
        
    }

 public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, bool isIncludeDelete = false)
 {
     using var dbContext = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

     var query = dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(where);

     if (isIncludeDelete) query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
     return await query.ToListAsync();
 }

}
```

The `BookRepository`  class.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace xxx;

public class BookRepository : BaseRepository<Book>, IBookRepository
{
    public BookRepository(IDbContextFactory<AppContext> dbContextFactory) : base(dbContextFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

When I update NET8 and EF core 8,and use `_bookRepository.GetListAsync()` that exception is thrown...
When I used EF core 7, the program worked correctly..

I read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283329/migration-problem-in-net-8-and-ef-core-8-preview-version-unable-to-create-a-d), it doesn't work...

Comment: Got the same exception yesterday when upgrading. First remove/upgrade all 'preview' and 'rc1' packages. The thing is you don't need to explicitly reference those packages, they are included in .net 8. And then DOWNGRADE 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySq' to version 7.0.

Comment: remove/upgrade all 'preview' and 'rc1' packages:NONE    and DOWNGRADE 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' to version 7.0 ...BUT NOT WORK

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, you CAN use 'Pomelo 8.0.0-beta.1'. But remove all that starts with: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore' (If you can't compile, add one at a time again).

Comment: @PoulBak It worked! Thank you! !

Comment: I also experience this issue just right now.
If you are working with MariaDb with DotNet 8.0 stable Released yesterday, you may using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?
If yes, you should wait Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql release next version, because it still beta-1 on Nuget and not compatiable with DotNet 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Mr Poul Bak's step,A temporary solution to the problem

```
<ItemGroup>
<!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>-->
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.0-beta.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Maybe the problem is this:
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.6
which version is larger than 8.0.0 .

Thanks again Mr Poul Bak!

Comment: It wouldn't work if Scaffold-DbContext in PMC.

Comment: They have now released 'Pomelo version 8.0.0-beta.2' and cleaned up the version mess. (it uses standard .net 8.0 files).Now I only need to reference 'Pomelo' and the rest will be referenced automatically.